# Need help to find solution for getA1Notation error

Tags: google-apps-script

I feel like my answer is here:Apply If/Then on a Range (google-apps-script) but I am getting an error for getA1Notation(). I have built a script on another document to auto-populate a row in my new document by trigger. Now, in the new document, I want to onEdit determine if column C has 2 values (separated by comma), then copy the row and split column C. Here is my code:

```js
function onEdit(){
  var targetSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Tech Newsletter - Current');
  var targetLastRow = targetSS.getLastRow();
  var targetNewRow = targetLastRow+1;

  var multipleMfg = targetSS.getRange("C"+targetLastRow).getValue();  
  if (multipleMfg.indexOf(",") !== -1) {
    var splitCell = '=SPLIT('+ multipleMfg.getA1Notation() + ',",")';
    targetNewRow.getRange("C").setFormula(splitCell);
  }
}
```

I realize I have more to add to get the rest of the row to populate, by I'm most worried about the Split and why I get the error "Cannot find function for getA1Notation in object Southern, Northern". I am a self taught scriptor, and I don't understand the definition provided on developers.google.com/apps-script/referece

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making confusion between different data types.

targetNewRow is an integer : it has no `getRange` method

multipleMfg is a string, it has no `getA1Notation` method

I changed a few things to make it work, see below:

```
function onEdit(){
  var targetSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('filters');
  var targetLastRow = targetSS.getLastRow();
  var targetNewRow = targetLastRow+1;
  var multipleMfg = targetSS.getRange("C"+targetLastRow).getValue();  
  if (multipleMfg.indexOf(",") !== -1) {
    var splitCell = multipleMfg.split(',');
    var result = [];
    for(var n in splitCell){
      result.push([splitCell[n]]);
    }
    targetSS.getRange(targetNewRow,3,result.length,result[0].length).setValues(result);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, but as usual, now I find a new error in my thinking... what was in C to begin with should stay (before the comma) and what is after the comma should populate in the row below column C, and continue down column C thereafter for as many comma's contained in the original submission. In editing the script the way you've outlined, Cell C stayed as it was, and the next row populated the first mfg in C and D, never returning the second mfg?